# Generate vector of 'random' proportions of a given length within specific boundaries

Tags: r

I want to generate a vector of a given length, e.g., n = 5. Each value in the vector should be a proportion (i.e., a value between 0 and 1) so that across n elements they sum up to 1.

Unfortunately, I have two vectors: one (mymins) defines the allowed lower boundaries of each proportion and the other (mymaxs) defines the allowed top boundaries of each proportion.

In my example below the desired proportion for the first element is allowed to fall anywhere between 0.3 and 0.9. And for the last element, the desired proportion is allowed to fall between 0.05 and 0.7.

```
mymins <- c(0.3, 0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.05)
mymaxs <- c(0.9, 1, 1, 1, 0.7)
```

Let's assume that mymins are always 'legitimate' (i.e., their sum is never larger than 1).

How could I find a set of 5 proportions such that they all sum to 1 but lie within the boundaries?

Here is what I tried:

```
n = 5
mydif <- mymaxs - mymins    # possible range for each proportion
myorder <- rank(mydif)      # order those differences from smallest to largest
mytarget <- sum(mydif)      # sum up the 5 ranges
x <- sort(runif(n))[myorder] # generate 5 random values an sort them in the order of mydif
x2 <- mymins + x / sum(x) * mytarget  # rescale random values to sum up to mytarget and add them to mymins
x3 <- x2/sum(x2)             # rescale x2 to sum up to 1
```

As you can see, I am not very far - because after rescaling some values are outside of their allowed boundaries.

I should probably also mention that I need this operation to be fast - because I am using it in an optimization loop.

I also tried to find a solution using optim, however the problem is that it always finds the same solution - and I need to generate a DIFFERENT solutions every time I find the proporotion:

```
    myfun <- function(x) {
      x <- round(x, 4)
      abovemins <- x - mymins
      n_belowmins <- sum(abovemins < 0)
      if (n_belowmins > 0) return(100000)
      belowmax <- x - mymaxs
      n_abovemax <- sum(belowmax > 0)
      if (n_abovemax > 0) return(100000)
      mydist <- abs(sum(x) - 1)
      return(mydist)
    }

    myopt <- optim(par = mymins + 0.01, fn = myfun)
    myopt$par
    sum(round(myopt$par, 4))
```

Thank you very much for your suggestions!

Comment: Since `sum(mymins)` is 1.2, you will never have a vector of random numbers that sum to 1.

Comment: Your code is incomplete: I don't know where `unif` comes from (`runif`?), and your last `sum` is missing a close-paren. Please make sure the code you've provided is your real code, copy/paste errors are difficult to work-through when they aren't the cause of the original question.

Comment: @r2evans Sorry - you are right, I have to reformulate the problem

Comment: `x <- runif(5, mymins, mymaxs) ; x/sum(x)` will initially meet your constraints and then be transformed so that they sum to 1. Is that what you need?

Comment: @r2evans  Unfortunately, you solution won't work. Rescaling breaks everything down. For example: mymins <- c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2); mymaxs <- c(0.2, 1, 0.2, 1, 0.2); x <- runif(5, mymins, mymaxs); x/sum(x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need 5 random numbers to sum to 1, you really only have 4 independent numbers and one dependent number.

```r
mymins <- c(0.3, 0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.05)
mymaxs <- c(0.9, 1, 1, 1, 0.7)

set.seed(42)
iter <- 1000
while(iter > 0 &&
        (
          (1 - sum(x <- runif(4, mymins[-5], mymaxs[-5]))) < mymins[5] ||
            (1 - sum(x)) > mymaxs[5]
        )
      ) iter <- iter - 1
if (iter < 1) {
  # failed
  stop("unable to find something within 1000 iterations")
} else {
  x <- c(x, 1-sum(x))
}

sum(x)
# [1] 1
all(mymins <= x & x <= mymaxs)
# [1] TRUE
x
# [1] 0.37732330 0.21618036 0.07225311 0.24250359 0.09173965
```

The reason I use `iter` there is to make sure you don't take an "infinite" amount of time to find something. If your `mymins` and `mymaxs` combination make this mathematically infeasible (as your first example was), then you don't need to spin forever. If it is mathematically improbable to find it in a reasonable amount of time, you need to weigh how long you want to do this.

One reason this takes so long is that we are iteratively pulling entropy. If you expect this to go for a long time, then it is generally better to pre-calculate as much as you think you'll need (overall) and run things as a matrix.

```r
set.seed(42)
n <- 10000
m <- matrix(runif(prod(n, length(mymins)-1)), nrow = n)
m <- t(t(m) * (mymaxs[-5] - mymins[-5]) + mymins[-5])
remainders <- (1 - rowSums(m))
ind <- mymins[5] <= remainders & remainders <= mymaxs[5]
table(ind)
# ind
# FALSE  TRUE 
#  9981    19 
m <- cbind(m[ind,,drop=FALSE], remainders[ind])
nrow(m)
# [1] 19
rowSums(m)
#  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
head(m)
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
# [1,] 0.3405821 0.1306152 0.05931363 0.2199362 0.24955282
# [2,] 0.3601376 0.1367465 0.20235704 0.2477507 0.05300821
# [3,] 0.4469526 0.1279795 0.02265618 0.2881733 0.11423845
# [4,] 0.5450527 0.1029903 0.07503371 0.2052423 0.07168103
# [5,] 0.3161519 0.1469783 0.15290720 0.3268470 0.05711557
# [6,] 0.4782448 0.1185735 0.01664063 0.2178225 0.16871845
all(
  mymins[1] <= m[,1] & m[,1] <= mymaxs[1],
  mymins[2] <= m[,2] & m[,2] <= mymaxs[2],
  mymins[3] <= m[,3] & m[,3] <= mymaxs[3],
  mymins[4] <= m[,4] & m[,4] <= mymaxs[4],
  mymins[5] <= m[,5] & m[,5] <= mymaxs[5]
)
# [1] TRUE
```

This time it took 10000 attempts to make 19 valid combinations. It might take more or fewer attempts based on randomness, so ymmv with regards to how much you need to pre-generate.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps its better to think of this in a different way. Your samples actually need to sum to 0.35 (which is 1 - sum(mymins)), then be added on to the minimum values

```r
constrained_sample <- function(mymins, mymaxs)
{
 sizes <- mymaxs - mymins
 samp <- (runif(5) * sizes)
 samp/sum(samp) * (1 - sum(mymins)) + mymins
}
```

It works like this:

```
constrained_sample(mymins, mymaxs)
#> [1] 0.31728333 0.17839397 0.07196067 0.29146744 0.14089459
```

We can test this works by running the following loop, which will print a message to the console if any of the criteria aren't met:

```
for(i in 1:1000)
{
  test <- constrained_sample(mymins, mymaxs)
  if(!all(test > mymins) | !all(test < mymaxs) | abs(sum(test) - 1) > 1e6) cat("failure")
}
```

This throws no errors, since the criteria are always met. However, as @GregorThomas points out, the bounds aren't realistic in this case. We can see a range of solutions constrained by your conditions using a boxplot:

```r
samp <- constrained_sample(mymins, mymaxs)
for(i in 1:999) samp <- rbind(samp, constrained_sample(mymins, mymaxs))
df <- data.frame(val = c(samp[,1], samp[,2], samp[,3], samp[,4], samp[,5]), 
                 index = factor(rep(1:5, each = 1000)))
ggplot(df, aes(x = index, y = val)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't really work, e.g. with mymins <- c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2); mymaxs <- c(0.25, 1, 0.25, 1, 0.35) every solution is always the same - c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2) - and I need varying solutions every iteration.

Comment: @user3245256 but that's the expected answer in that case - if the probability has to sum to one and all minimum values sum to one, the only possible solution is the minimum values!  Try to come up with a different set of values that sums to 1 if the minimum probabilities are all 0.2. You can't do it1 Try it with minimum values that sum to less than one, and you'll see it's always different.

Answer (score 2):

If your example bounds are realistic, we can refine them quite a bit, narrowing the range of possibilities. For the current version of the question with:

```
mymins = c(0.3, 0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.05)
mymaxs = c(0.9, 1, 1, 1, 0.7)
```

What's the max for `x[1]`? Well, if `x[2:5]` take on minimum values, they will add up to `0.1 + 0 + 0.2 + 0.05 = 0.35`, so based on the *other mins only* we know that max value for `x[1]` is `1 - 0.35 = 0.65`. The `0.9` in `mymaxs` is way too high.

We can calculate the actual max values taking the minimum of the max values based on the minimums and the `mymaxs` vector:

```
new_max = pmin(mymaxs, 1 - (sum(mymins) - mymins))
new_max
# [1] 0.65 0.45 0.35 0.55 0.40
```

We can similarly revise the min bounds, though in this case even the revised max bounds `new_max` are high enough that it would have any impact on the minimums.

```
new_min = pmax(mymins, 1 - (sum(new_max) - new_max))
new_min
# [1] 0.30 0.10 0.00 0.20 0.05
```

With these adjustments, we should be able to see easily if any solutions are possible (`all(new_min < new_max)`). And then generating random numbers as in r2evans's answer should go much quicker using the new bounds.

Comment: You are right about the bounds - I have added a plot to show this, but why use a search and reject method rather than directly sampling the constrained sample space? Is there a flaw in my reasoning about the direct method?

Comment: I don't see one... I hadn't read your answer thoroughly and based on the text I thought you were just using the mins, not the maxs. But I guess we're doing the same operations for our revised maxs...

Comment: Wow, I think it's working. So, the end of the solution you proposed is like this? x <- runif(5, new_min, new_max); x/sum(x) # Correct?

Comment: Actually, sorry, it's not working (unless I misunderstood). I ran your code and then several times x <- runif(5, new_min, new_max); x/sum(x). Sometimes the solution is within bounds, but sometimes it's not.

Comment: Or maybe you meant his solution with iterations? So, inside his 'while' loop I am using new_min and new_max. And it's working - it is satisfying the conditions. However, I noticed that the new maxs are quite a bit lower than the original ones, so that in the solution the values found are considerably below the original maxes. But it's probably the result of all the other constraints?

Comment: In reference to my previous comment: I tried mymins <- c(0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.05) and
mymaxs <- c(0.2, 1, 0.2, 1, 0.7). And, after generating many solutions, the first proportion is almost never >0.6 and only once above 0.7. Interesting...

Comment: @user3245256 does this give a different range of answers to those in my solution? Just curious.

Comment: @user3245256 All I'm doing is systematically narrowing the bounds---and getting the bounds as small as possible does not mean that every draw from within those bounds will work. See the other answers for sampling methods. Allan Cameron's solution seems to do very well for that.

Comment: @user3245256 I'd add that the bounds of Allan Cameron's boxplot has bounds that match my revised bounds---which makes me think that his answer works well. If you use r2evans's "try until you find something that works" approach, using these narrowed bounds instead of the original wide bounds should make the process much quicker.